# Dynamic Assignment of 'Null' to LONG object in Java?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, long-integer

Following statement is throwing Null pointer exception:

```
Long a = obj.getCase().getCaseID()
```

obj is not null

getCase is not null

getCaseID() is returning null which is of Long type.

Can't 'Null' assign directly to 'Long a' to Long object directly? 
If not how to handle these Runtime situation; other then applying simple null checks?

Comment: you should be able to return null on that but you say getCase() is not null? What about obj is that null? you have 3 possible nulls there obj obj.getCase() and case.getCaseId()

Comment: No Obj is not null thats why getCase is not null.

Comment: What is the returntype of getCaseID()

Comment: It is some object which have getter setter in which "Long caseID" is one of property.

Comment: I was asking wondering if there was any autoboxing happening long versus Long

Comment: *"Following statement is throwing Null pointer exception"* Then one of these things is true: 1. `obj` is `null` (even though you say it isn't). 2. Code within `getCase` is using a `null` and throwing (e.g., it doesn't return). 3. `obj.getCase()` returns `null` (even though you said it doesn't). 4. Code within `getCaseID` is trying to use a `null` and throwing (e.g., it doesn't return). What is *not* happening is that `getCaseID` is returning `null`, as that will not cause an NPE.

Comment: getCase is not null and getCaseId is simply "return caseID"

Comment: That is obvious if any of obj and getCase is null it will throw NPE; but in my case it is getCaseID which simply "return caseID" which is declared ob top private Long caseID;...

Comment: I would recommend stepping through your code with a debugger - as TJ Crowder said, if `getCaseID` was actually returning, you wouldn't be getting this error.

Comment: If `getCaseID()` is `long getCaseID()` it will throw an NPE if you try to return a `Long` which is `null`. I suggest you break up the statement into multiple lines and look very carefully for the line which throws the exception.

Comment: And if @PeterLawrey is right (which is a bet I'd take), you could have had that answer ~12 minutes ago by including the minimum involved code in the question. (It's also scenario #4 in my comment above; the unboxing code in `getCaseID` auto-generated by the compiler trying to dereference `null`.)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: getCaseID() is 'Long' but it is getting set to another variable in next line which is 'long' not 'Long'. It could be the reason?

Comment: @fatherazrael you can't assign a `null` to a `long` but that would be a different line of code. Have a look at the line of code the error actually occurs on to work out if this is the cause.

Answer (score -1):

```
Long a = obj.getCase().getCaseID() != null ? obj.getCase().getCaseID():0;
System.out.print(a); // if this prints 0 then you object retuns null
```

Comment: How does this help?